# Headphones are not detected in the front panel

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, front-panel

Recently I changed my operative system from Windows XP to Windows 7 64 bits. After that I cannot get my earphones working when I plugged them in the jack of the front panel. I have a

My motherboard is:

```
 Model  GA-M55PLUS-S3G
 North Bridge   NVIDIA GeForce 6100 Revision A2
 South Bridge   NVIDIA nForce 410/430 MCP Revision A2
```

so I've updated its drivers int this [page](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2283#ov). After that  when I plug the speakers in the back panel I can see that the jack is detected and the realtek HP program ask me which type of device has been plugged. But when I plug a headphones in the front one nothing is detected (even when the speakers are plugged or not in the back one). I haven't changed nothing in the hardware so it must be a problem of the configuration. When I used  XP both work (though if I connected something in the back panel no sound appear in the front one)

Any idea?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I've got it working but with a very weird configuration:

In the RealTek configuration I go to Device advance settings and I select "Silence the device in the back output when the headphones are plugged in the front panel" and in the  configuration of the conector (just below  Device advance settings) I mark "Disable the detection of the jack in the front panel" and with this configuration I can hear both the speakers in the back jack and the headphones in the front one. It's completely weird!!

Comment: Windows 7 is not very good with some machines... I installed one in a notebook that had Windows XP and its sound functioned perfectly until I installed Windows 7. Now the sound is noisy, like when it is "saturated" (e.g. take a sound file and edit it in Audacity, increasing volume/amplitude 300% and you will hear a sound like that notebook sound output)

Comment: you solved your issue, so answer your question below and assign "the answer" to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Do double-check that it is connected properly inside the machine.  Even though you didn't change any hardware, there is that small possibility that something did get disconnected (perhaps the wire was just on the verge of disconnecting from the motherboard?).

Once that's ruled out, then look at the software -- you might save yourself a lot of hassle running around in circles trying to get software working for hardware that's simply not hooked up.

Comment: It would be very unprobable. I've found a way to get it working but it doesn't make any sense. See my update.